# Place Font-Awesome-5 Icon as Bootstrap-4 Card background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want to use a Font Awesome 5 icon as card background image using Bootstrap-4!

I tried everything what I found from the internet but nothing worked.

I'm using Angular2 (v8) along with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me. I've simplified what I use but you still get a font-awesome icon as background and you can put text on top of it:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 d-flex">
    <div class="class-box">
    <div class="bg-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-question big-centered-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
    <h3 class="title-bg text-outline"><Strong>TITLE</Strong></h3>   
    <h4 class="title-bg text-outline">Subtitle</h4>
    <h4 class="title-bg text-outline"><Strong> Subtitle</Strong></h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 d-flex">
    <div class="class-box">
    <div class="bg-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-question big-centered-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
    <h3 class="title-bg text-outline"><Strong>HELLO</Strong></h3>   
    <h3 class="title-bg text-outline"><Strong> 2nd HELLO</Strong></h3>
    <h3 class="title-bg text-outline"><Strong> 3rd HELLO</Strong></h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.big-centered-icon {
font-size: 144px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
display: flex; /* add */
justify-content: center; /* add to align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* add to align vertical */
}

.class-box{ text-align:center;position:relative;margin:8px;width: 100%;padding-bottom: 75%}
div.class-box > div { position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;overflow:hidden;padding-top:15%}
.class-box .title-bg{font-size:24px;color:#000;}
```

[See the working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/es41qm0t/)

Comment: This is not what I looked for. I think you misunderstood me. In general thats okay, but I cannot place any text over this icon. It appears always next to it e.g

Comment: @b0ss: I've edited the code and now, I guess, does what you were looking for

Comment: Change the class col-md-4 col-sm-6 to an smaller one (looks at boostrap docs, col-2 may do the trick for you)